# I m learning Topic Non Linear Regression for ML . I am unable to understand the given line

Tags: python, machine-learning, non-linear-regression

```
x = np.arange(-5.0, 5.0, 0.1)

##You can adjust the slope and intercept to verify the changes in the graph
y = 2*(x) + 3
y_noise = 2 * np.random.normal(size=x.size)
ydata = y + y_noise
#plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
plt.plot(x, ydata,  'bo')
plt.plot(x,y, 'r')
plt.ylabel('Dependent Variable')
plt.xlabel('Indepdendent Variable')
plt.show()
```

```
y_noise = 2 * np.random.normal(size=x.size)
ydata = y + y_noise
```

Comment: What _specific_ part of the line do you not understand? What documentation did you read to try to understand it, and how/why was what that documentation said unclear?

Comment: See [How to handle "please explain ${this code dump} questions"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894/how-to-handle-explain-how-this-code-dump-works-questions) for discussion of why questions of this form are not on-topic unless you explain more about how and why it's unclear.

Comment: (We don't know what part you don't understand: Do you understand the _mechanics_ of the line just fine, but not understand its purpose? Or did a class you're taking or book you're reading describe the purpose, but not say the mechanics by which that purpose is accomplished? In any event, edit the question to describe the problem in more detail instead of adding comments: If you know what _some_ of the mechanics mean but not others, tell us what you think the parts you _do_ understand accomplish).

Comment: Will do it Thanks for the suggestions

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please also read [ask] and make sure you understand that this is *not a discussion forum*.

Comment: Your edit provides more context, but it still doesn't say _why_ you don't understand those two lines. Do you know what `*` does? What `+` does? What `np.random.normal()` does in general or in theory? Did you read the documentation for `np.random.normal()`? What part of the contents of that documentation was unclear? Spell all that out _in the question itself_.